# ConTeXt issue after texlive-binaries update

Tags: texlive

I work in a group with six people, all with Jammy Jellyfish Ubuntu, and since last week we have no longer been able to compile tex files of the ConTeXt type.

```
fatal error : unable to load bytecode register 544, maybe wipe the cache first

system          | total runtime: 6.660 seconds
```

We tried to reinstall TeX Live without success. We even tried to install in a brand new machine. ButD during installation, the process stops exactly due to a problem with ConTeXt. We tried to downgrade texlive-binaries, but apparently it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to downgrade texlive-binaries by using aptitude with the following:

```
 sudo aptitude install texlive-binaries=2021.20210626.59705-1build1
```

It proposes several solutions, the one to accept in my case was:

```
       Downgrade the following packages:
1)     libkpathsea6 [2021.20210626.59705-1ubuntu0.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now) -> 2021.20210626.59705-1build1 (jammy)]
2)     libptexenc1 [2021.20210626.59705-1ubuntu0.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now) -> 2021.20210626.59705-1build1 (jammy)]
3)     libsynctex2 [2021.20210626.59705-1ubuntu0.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now) -> 2021.20210626.59705-1build1 (jammy)]
4)     libtexlua53 [2021.20210626.59705-1ubuntu0.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now) -> 2021.20210626.59705-1build1 (jammy)]
5)     libtexluajit2 [2021.20210626.59705-1ubuntu0.2 (jammy-security, jammy-updates, now) -> 2021.20210626.59705-1build1 (jammy)]
```

After this you can hold the package for now with:

```
apt-mark hold texlive-binaries
```